# ROS support in Windows 10 tablet + Qt GUI application

Tags: ros-kinetic, windows, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to create an Qt GUI (using qml) application which is targeted to run on a windows 10 tablet. Whether ROS can be installed in mobile or tablet platforms.

I have a windows tablet UI application and planning to 1) Subscribe for a ROS topic and ROS data 2) Update the application GUI , based on the data received from ROS node.

Is there any alternative solution develop GUI application with ROS , to run on a mobile platform.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280973/ros-support-in-windows-10-tablet-+-qt-gui-application/) by [Parvathy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29108/parvathy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-26**:
Don't know about Win10, but: [bgromov/ros_qml](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml) and [severin-lemaignan/ros-qml-plugin](https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/ros-qml-plugin).

**Comment by [Parvathy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29108/parvathy/) on 2018-01-27**:
Ok.. thanks for the reply,,,
But i want to know whether it is supported in a mobile/ tablet application?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-27**:
No idea. It's QML, so my answer would be: maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a lot of work ROS can be made to run on Windows but it takes a lot of work and is not a supported platform. (For ROS2 it is a supported platform) If you want a web based GUI that can work on a tablet I recommend checking out [Robot Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
There is #q238646, but it's also unsupported (and most tablets run the ARM version of Win10, which doesn't have WSL iirc).